# want to know single date one by one is working date or not/holiday

Tags: mysql, database

My function is working perfectly when I pass the complete month date start and end date it return the count of working days in a month but I want to pass the start and end date the same and want to know that is it a single date working day or not.
here is my working function kindly change to help me to find out a single date as it is working date or not.
one more thing is that **before 15 date all saturdays are working days and after 15 date all saturdays are company holidays this work is also done in this function**
Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN_CNT_Working_days(StartDate DATE,
                                EndDate   DATE) 
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE WORKING_DAYS INT;
SELECT
(DATEDIFF(EndDate, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16))) + 1)
-(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(EndDate, DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16)))/7) * 2)
-(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 16))) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
 +
 (DATEDIFF(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 15)), StartDate) + 1)
 -(FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(EndDate), '-', MONTH(EndDate), '-', 15)), StartDate)/7))
 -(CASE WHEN DAYNAME(StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 INTO WORKING_DAYS;

 RETURN (WORKING_DAYS);
END;
```

Comment: tag your database correctly.

Comment: @Sudipta Mondal any database I will use that in my project currently using MySQL but will transfer to oracle once the project is going live